# Web Worker always 25% slower than main thread with expensive operations on Canvas pixels

Tags: javascript, html, multithreading, performance, web-worker

I made a simple application, which takes photo from `video` tag and make it gray, available in full here: [Canvas WebWorker PoC](https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/Canvas-WebWorker-PoC):

```
const photoParams = [         
    0, //x
    0, //y
    320, //width
    240, //height
];
async function startVideo () {
  const stream = await navigator.mediaDevices.getUserMedia({
      audio: false,
      video: true,
  });
  const video = document.querySelector('#video');
  video.srcObject = stream;
  video.play();
  return video;
}

function takePhoto () {
    const video = document.querySelector('#video');
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 240;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, ...photoParams);

    const imageData = applyFilter({imageData: 
    context.getImageData(...photoParams)});
    context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

    return canvas.toDataURL("image/png")
}

function setPhoto () {
    const photo = takePhoto();
    const image = document.querySelector('#image');
    image.src = photo;
}

startVideo();
const button = document.querySelector('#button');
button.addEventListener('click', setPhoto);
```

In one of functions, I placed long, unnecessary `for` loop to make it really slow:

```
function transformPixels ({data}) {
    let rawPixels;
    const array = new Array(2000);
    for (element of array) {
        rawPixels = [];
        const pixels = getPixels({
            data,
        });
        const filteredPixels = [];
        for (const pixel of pixels) {
            const average = getAverage(pixel);
            filteredPixels.push(new Pixel({
                red: average,
                green: average,
                blue: average,
                alpha: pixel.alpha,
            }));
        }
        for (const pixel of filteredPixels) {
            rawPixels.push(...pixel.toRawPixels());
        }
    }
    return rawPixels;
};
```

And I created Web Worker version which, as I thougt, should be faster cause it not break the main thread:

```
function setPhotoWorker () {
    const video = document.querySelector('#video');
    const canvas = document.querySelector('#canvas');
    canvas.width = 320;
    canvas.height = 240;
    const context = canvas.getContext('2d');
    context.drawImage(video, ...photoParams);
    const imageData = context.getImageData(...photoParams);

    const worker = new Worker('filter-worker.js');
    worker.onmessage = (event) => {
        const rawPixelsArray = [...JSON.parse(event.data)];
        rawPixelsArray.forEach((element, index) => {
            imageData.data[index] = element;
        });
        context.putImageData(imageData, 0, 0);

        const image = document.querySelector('#image');
        image.src = canvas.toDataURL("image/png");
    }
    worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify([...imageData.data]));
}
```

Which could be run in this way:

```
button.addEventListener('click', setPhotoWorker);
```

Worker code is almost exactly the same as single-threaded version, except one thing - to improve messaging performance, [string is sent instead of array of numbers](https://nolanlawson.com/2016/02/29/high-performance-web-worker-messages/):

```
worker.onmessage = (event) => {
    const rawPixelsArray = [...JSON.parse(event.data)];
};
//...
worker.postMessage(JSON.stringify([...imageData.data]));
```

And inside `filter-worker.js`:

```
onmessage = (data) => {
    const rawPixels = transformPixels({data: JSON.parse(data.data)});
    postMessage(JSON.stringify(rawPixels));
};
```

The problem is that **worker version is always about 20-25% slower than main thread version**. First I thought it may be size of message, but in my laptop I have 640 x 480 camera, which gives 307 200 items - which I don't think are expensive enough to be reason why, for 2000 `for` iterations, leads to results: main thread: about 160 seconds, worker about 200 seconds. You can download app from [Github repo](https://github.com/radek-anuszewski/Canvas-WebWorker-PoC) and check it on your own. The pattern is quite the same here - worker is always 20-25% slower. Without using `JSON API`, worker needs something like 220 seconds to finish its job. The only one reason which I thought is that worker thread has very low priority, and in my application, where main thread has not too much things to do it is simply slower - and in real-world app, where main thread might be busier, worker will win. Do you have any ideas why worker is so slow? Thank you for every answer.

Comment: I would guess that the majority of the slowdown is caused by interfacing with the canvas. The grayscale calculation is probably not the bottleneck. The worker version adds overhead of stringifying and parsing. Try using performance.now()'s to figure out where the slow downs are.

Comment: @bruceceng But I am interfacing with canvas in the main thread, Worker has just simple data without any connotations to canvas, definetely tommorow I will try with performance now, however stringifying and parsing are "constant price", but I saw that Worker is slower even in big `for` loop (from 50 operations to 2000 operations I saw the same pattern, Worker is 25% slower). Thank you for your advice with performance.now(), I will check it